# Basic authentication Https SSL Android, loopj library

Tags: java, authentication, https, basic-authentication, loopj

I can not pass authentication in HTTPS using loopj Asnctask Http library. How can you implement it and what else do I need to add to my code.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
etLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
btnJoin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJoin);

String username = etLogin.getText().toString();
String password = etLogin.getText().toString();
final String url = "https://IpAddress:Port/index.php/api/user";
final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setBasicAuth(username,password, new AuthScope("IP", Port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM));
client.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));


btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                Log.d("App", "Connected");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("App","Upload Failed!");
                Log.d("App","Error Message: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("App", "Error Cause: " + error.getCause());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

He writes in the log:

Log.d:

```
09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Upload Failed!
09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Error Message: UnknownHostException exception: Unable to resolve host "host5.istv.uz": No address associated with hostname
09-06 05:20:27.471 1254-1254/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp D/App: Error Cause: null
```

All log:

```
09-06 05:20:27.407 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
09-06 05:20:27.407 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 
09-06 05:20:27.415 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289) 
09-06 05:20:27.415 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:464) 
09-06 05:20:27.423 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65) 
09-06 05:20:27.427 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177) 
09-06 05:20:27.431 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145) 
09-06 05:20:27.431 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131) 
09-06 05:20:27.443 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611) 
09-06 05:20:27.443 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446) 
09-06 05:20:27.451 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860) 
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) 
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)        
09-06 05:20:27.455 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177) 
09-06 05:20:27.459 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106) 
09-06 05:20:27.459 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390) 
09-06 05:20:27.463 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
09-06 05:20:27.463 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
09-06 05:20:27.467 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
09-06 05:20:27.467 1254-1282/uz.istv.jsonparsingtestapp W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can set Basic Auth like that...

```
    client.setBasicAuth("UserName", "Password");
```

More details [loopj](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/)